# Paypal buttons disappear in the text editor

Tags: paypal

I have a series of paypal buttons on a web page that I am trying to migrate from another site onto Wordpress.

When I copy the html and paste it into the (HTML TAB) of the wordpress editor, I can see the buttons. But when I press save the code disappears...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements like these (PayPal buttons), *should not* be inserted as page content in the editor, but in your WordPress template files.

I assume you are developing your own WordPress theme! If not, you can modify an existing shipped WordPress theme such as the *Twenty Eleven* WordPress theme.

Depending on the placement of the button, you should do it in `header.php`, `sidebar.php` or `footer.php`, all, of your selected WordPress theme.